# Still connected with Google

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-signin, gidsignin

I put GIDButton on my application. It works very well.

But when the user has finished logging in and closes the application, he has to login again. That's the problem.

Does someone know how can I let the user stay logged in?

Thanks

Comment: You need to login silently `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()`

Answer (score 1):

When a user signs in with Google, Google SDK stores user's password on the keychain. After the app is killed the login state is gone (but the keychain item maybe not), for that you can check whether the password has been stored in the keychain and sign the user in silently again (without user's interaction).

```
// Possibly show an activity indicator here
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
    // Sign in user without interaction
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
} else {
    // Show sign in flow
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

Later in your code, handle the delegate callback:

```
extension YourLoginManager: GIDSignInDelegate {
    public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    // Possibly remove the activity indicator
    if user != nil {
        // Do stuff that a logged in user does
    }
}
```

To conclude - you don't let the user stay logged in when the app is killed, but rather you recreate the logged in state by doing "silent" sign in.

p.s. If you want to sign the user out and remove the keychain item call: `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()`

Comment: But when I launch the app, hasAuthInKeychain() always return false whereas I have already connected my Google Account

Comment: Are you sure you're not disconnecting the user before you do silent sign in?

Comment: Make sure before you check for `hasAuthInKeychain()` and call `signInSilently()` that you've set up clientId, scopes, delegate, etc.

Comment: @Au Ris Can you please explain the difference between GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn() & GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently() AND GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect() & GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()